# CheckList beofore creating Large table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I am creating a new table where billions of records will be added in the future.table will look something like below.

```
Book name                     | pages | author
-------------------------------------------
book name of 6 to 20 letters | 349    | notme
string of 6 to 20 letters    | 200    | notyou
```

I will be using the search feature with auto fill.For example if I type `gr`

It should search based on book name and return all the book names with pages and authors name..like for example see below

```
amazon green house effect : 349 : name
grow old stronger         :300  : name
.
.
.
and so on upto 10 or 20 records sorted by page numbers or something..
```

So after adding  billions of records i know it will become slow while querying..so what are the steps i must take before creating a table in order to maintain the speed and efficienct even after data are more than billions.(prevention is better than cure ;) )

What i learnt ?

I learnt about creating **indexes**.Is it better to create **index** before table creation ? Or any other ideas are welcome.If you where in my position what are all the things ull do.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Add an Index on the Table during creation and update it on a regular Basis using

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE myTable
```

Have a look at MySQLs [full-text search Features](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), too.

Comment: update on the regular basis in the sense ? run the Optimize table command ?

Comment: Yes. The `OPTIMZE` Statement will update the index statistics each time you run it.